# What is swift_MagicMirrorData_summaryImpl?

Tags: swift

There's a function defined in the Swift module

```
func swift_MagicMirrorData_summaryImpl(metadata: Any.Type, result: UnsafePointer<String>)
```

Googling "swift_MagicMirrorData_summaryImpl" provides only three results so far.  What is it used for?

I've found that I can get an Any.Type using

```
"someString".getMirror().valueType
```

But I'm struggling to initialize an `UnsafePointer<String>`, or figure out a use for this function.

The fact that it has the word "magic" in it piques my curiosity. How do I use this magic function?

Answer (score 0):

This function is connected with the `Mirror` protocol somehow.

All that `Mirror` stuff you get when invoking `reflect(...)` is probably implemented only to provide some API for the IDE inspector and you shouldn't use it at all.

All objects conforming to `Mirror` have the `summary` method:

```
/// Get a string description of this value.
var summary: String { get }
```

The summary is that simple string you see when you attempt to print something that is not printable, e.g. :

```
"C9SwiftTest11AppDelegate (has 2 children)"
```